# pandas - string to list to dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have the following problem, I'm trying to convert the strings in a pandas df into lists so that I can later structure them as a dict. Please see below:

My data is coming in as a string in a pandas df, i.e.

`df['users'].iloc[0] = "str1|str2, str3|str4"`

..... And so on for the series.

From here I split the strings as such:

`df['users'] = df['users'].map(lambda x: re.split("[',|']",x))`, which returns a list `[str1, str2, str3, str4]`.

So far so good. The challenge I haven't been able to resolve is taking said list and structure it as a dictionary such that I would produce the following:

`[{
  field1: str1
  field2: str2
  field3: 
  field4: 
},{
  field1: str3
  field2: str4
  field3: 
  field4:
}]`

where the empty fields could be filled out later (optional).

Is there a better way to structure the data in order to make this goal easier? i.e. have the list as `[[str1, str2],[str3, str4]]`

How would I go about 'zipping' these values from this lists with the name name of the fields (field1, filed2, ...)?

In essence, the final output should contain the dictionary above in each cell of the df where the original string used to reside.

Can anyone offer insights? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### list of lists

```
df.users.map(
    lambda s: [x.split('|') for x in s.split(', ')]
)

0    [[str1, str2], [str3, str4]]
Name: users, dtype: object
```

---

### Dictionaries using f-strings

```
df.users.map(
    lambda s: [
        {f'field{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(x.split('|'), 1)}
        for x in s.split(', ')
    ]
)

0    [{'field1': 'str1', 'field2': 'str2'}, {'field...
Name: users, dtype: object
```

---

### With pre determined fields

```
fields = 'field1 field2 field3 field4'.split()

df.users.map(
    lambda s: [dict(zip(fields, x.split('|'))) for x in s.split(', ')]
)

0    [{'field1': 'str1', 'field2': 'str2'}, {'field...
Name: users, dtype: object
```

### If you want all fields

```
from itertools import zip_longest

fields = 'field1 field2 field3 field4'.split()

df.users.map(
    lambda s: [dict(zip_longest(fields, x.split('|'))) for x in s.split(', ')]
)
```

Comment: This is awesome !!

Comment: @piRSquared This is great, but there are always 4 fields and I don't necessarily need to name them 1-2, they could be static, i.e. Br, Ct, Ma, Ft. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @piRSquared tried the above, the lists of list bit works fine but I get the following error for the predetermined fields section: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: you've accidentally overwritten the `dict` name with something else.  Find where you assigned to it and change it.  If in Jupyter, do `del dict` then try the solution again.

Comment: @piRSquared Got it working. I'll accept your answer. Thank you so much for this, you are a panda master/master panda? One more thing, why is it that field3 and field 4 don't show up? I need them there regardless if they have a value or not. I could assign it later.

Comment: If you need them, use `ziplongest` as @VictorK. suggested.  Even consider upvoting his answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help (assuming that there are always exactly four fields):

```
import itertools
import pprint

FIELDS = [
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'field3',
    'field4',
]

test_str = "str1|str2, str3|str4"
items = test_str.split(',')
results = [
    # Pads non-existent fields with `None`.
    dict(itertools.zip_longest(FIELDS, item.split('|')))
    for item in items
]

pprint.pprint(results)
# Returns:
# [{'field1': 'str1', 'field2': 'str2', 'field3': None, 'field4': None},
#  {'field1': ' str3', 'field2': 'str4', 'field3': None, 'field4': None}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the zip_longest trick worked wonders!

Comment: @JohnWayne360 Glad to hear it! :)